# postgresql - Disallow getting list of databases

Tags: postgresql, permissions, psql

How can I disallow getting list of databases on the PostgreSQL server? That can be done (for example) using `\l` in `psql`.

Comment: I don't think this is possible without hacking the data dictionary views, which is generally a bad idea. Is restricting access to databases not enough security-wise? Is there some sort of shared hosting setup involved?

Comment: already asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3349136/how-to-prevent-a-user-from-being-able-to-see-other-databases-and-the-tables-from)

Comment: You could easily run different PostgreSQL servers on the same machine (on different ports obviously) - there would be no visibilty there!  Check out multi-tenancy and consolidation/centralization and the pros and cons associated with each technique - there is no silver bullet! :-(

Comment: @Vérace, this looks like the best option because the databases are completely separated.

Comment: Do you wish me to make it into an answer - I can add in all sorts of goodies about multi-tenant vs. monolithic!

Comment: @Vérace, Yes, I do. I am quite new to PostgreSQL so I want as much information as possible.

Comment: Check out multi tenancy vs. single tenant (search and preface with `user:34007`). Check out all of those threads and that should get you going. [This](https://vladmihalcea.com/database-multitenancy/) is good. Bear in mind the pros and cons (backups, security, isolation, hware failures...). Of course, with cloud, virtualisation and containerisation, the possibilities are endless. HTH.